# Angular ui-grid filtering based on date is null or not null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid, angular-filters

In my application i am using Angular [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) to display set of data in a grid format . I want to filter these data based on a Date field called `actionDate` . I want to filter data where the `actionDate` is `null` or `not null`. I am using a simple dropdown to select this .

But the filtering doesn't work when this `actionDate` field is not null . I think the reason this doesn't work is that the `actionDate` field has different values and the ui-grid filter fails to understand that .

I have reproduced this issue in the following plunker. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/8rIJeA92hDYQ9vHDUC1C?p=preview

Appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your issues in [this fork of your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dq3Q8KIfsvFqCkCx582z?p=preview).

UPDATE: Ok, well, the solution I've employed is to add a hidden column called `dateActionedKey` at the end of your `colDefs`:

```
{ 
   field: 'dateActionedKey', 
   filter: {
     term: $scope.term
   }, 
   visible: false 
}
```

The problem was that you were filtering the column by a property you assigned after the fact -- if has no `actionDate`, value is '1', else value is `actionDate` -- but your filter selector filters by `id`, looking for values '1' or '2'.

So you need to change your `forEach` function from:

```
_.forEach(data, function (value) {
    value.dateActioned = value.dateActioned===null ? '1' : value.dateActioned;
});
```

to:

```
_.forEach(data, function (value) {
    value.dateActionedKey = value.dateActioned===null ? '1' : '2';
});
```

By adding in the extra property `dateActionedKey`, you can just assign it the binary 1 or 2 value and nothing changes in your display. And since this invisible column is now the last of seven, you need to update the filter term assignment to:

```
$scope.gridApi.grid.columns[6].filter.term = $scope.term;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That is exactly kind of solution i was looking for . Thanks :)